# unity 7 ubuntu 13.04 default behaviour when click on icon run application and move to the workspace that contains this runned app

Tags: unity, launcher, workspaces

In 12.04 this is a default behaviour.

When i upgraded to 13.04 that does not occur.

When I launch one instance of any example application and switch to other desktop (fro example from up-left to down-right workspace) via Super+S keyboard and then want to see my runned app unity don't switch my workspace to workspace that contain my app.

Why this is by default ?

How can I change this behavior ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: My problem and preference is quite the opposite to yours. In 14.04, this is what I see and dislike. Say I have a nautilus window open in workspace 1. When I switch to workspace 2 and click on the nautilus panel icon, unity switches to the nautilus window in workspace 1.

It seems this is the behavior you want, right?

Comment: Yes, I am also upgraded to 14.04 and see that this has been fixed in 14.04 )